# Run a Python script from C# with IronPython, without exposing system libraries

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

So I'm makin a program that needs to execute Python scripts (something like modding API), but I want to expose just a few modules that I have defined. Regardless, I still get access to the `System` module from the Python script, which I don't want. How do I disable this (what alternatives of IronPython do I use)

Comment: Do you have an "__ init __.py" somewhere?
if you make modules/packages, you can use the init to import the bare minimum. Put your main code ina separate file. Do you have the know-how to packaging in python? The packaging documentation is full of goodness, maybe you'll find something useful in it. Then ironpythong may be different...

Comment: All .NET apps have access to `System` automatically.

Comment: @TimRoberts what I meant is that I don't want Python to have access to `System`